# Javascript, jQuery - how signed actions to just created object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make simple list with ability to add and delete elements. For now I am working on adding and performing a simple action on each of list elements object (existing and added). Unfortunately I have met some difficulties with that. I am able to modify objects that are created at the beginning, but not one added during "webpage working".

First of all my idea was to add AJAX to this, but I don't think it is the easiest way.

I think that some time ago (I don't remember where) I read how to make this work, but now I don't know. I would be really glad if someone would help me with this or at least give a link to good explanation of this.

There is what I have done so far (well this is mostly just a scratch, but the main idea is in it): http://jsfiddle.net/sebap123/pAZ7H/0

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).text("new text");
});
$("#addButton").click(function() {
    $(".list").append(
    $('<li>').append($('<span>').append("added li")));
});​
```

Thank you for all responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use event-delegation, with the `on()` method:

```
$("ul").on('click','li', function() {
    $(this).text("OK");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pAZ7H/4/).

The problem you were experiencing is that jQuery can only directly bind events to already-present elements (present at the point of event-binding); the `on()` approach binds the action to the element to which the new content is added (or an ancestor element of the newly-added elements), identifies the events to listen for `'click'` (a space-separated list of events), that match the selector (`li`) and then the function performs the required actions.

If you're using jQuery 1.7 (or later) `on()` should be used, for versions of jQuery < 1.7, `delegate()` should be used instead (which does more or less the same thing, but reverses the event-list and the selector parameters):

```
$("ul").delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    $(this).text("OK");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pAZ7H/6/).

References:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thank you very much for great explanation of topic. I was just looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use event delegation here..
Try this

```
$("ul").on('click' , 'li', function() {
    $(this).text("OK");
});
```

The problem with the previous click event is that events are only attched to the current element's on the page..

But when you create a new element , no events are attached to the element.

You have two options here.. Either to delegate your event i.e; add the event listerner to the element's ancestor ..

Or add the event once the element is created..

2nd Approach

```
var clickEvent = function() {
    $('li').unbind().on('click', function() {
        $(this).text("OK");
    });
}

clickEvent();

$("#addButton").click(function() {
    $(".list").append(
    $('<li>').append($('<span>').append("Press me - I am new!")));
    clickEvent();
});​
```

In the second approach you are binding unbinding and binding the new event to all the elements once a new element is added..

Binding and again rebinding of events is a bad design pattern

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/pAZ7H/7/)

[2nd APPROACH](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/pAZ7H/10/)